# How to write a line of statement with two vector of different size using no loops In matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am not sure if the title is correct. But here's what I want to do.

```
n = -10:10;
p = [-0.6  0.2];
r = [ -1.7500  2.7500];
H = zeros(size(n));
for i=1:length(p)
   H = H + r(i)*(p(i).^n).*(n>=0);
end
```

I want to write this for loop in a one line statement. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

`H = (H + r(1)*(p(1).^n).*(n>=0))+(H + r(2)*(p(2).^n).*(n>=0))`

Comment: This code produces the same exact answer as the code you provided with the for loop. a vector `H [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1.6 -0.52 0.4 -0.2224 0.13696 -0.081472 0.0490 -0.0293 0.01763  -0.0105];`

Answer (score 0):

From Matlab 2016b, when you convert `r` and `p` to vertical vectors by the operator `.'`, you can multiply or power it by row vector `n`, and get the result as a matrix. That known as "arithmetic expands".  It can be very useful in your case:

```
H=sum(r.'.*p.'.^n).*(n>=0);
```

For earlier versions of Matlab, you need to use `bsxfun` for element-wise operations, so you can write it like that:

```
H=sum(bsxfun(@times,r.',bsxfun(@power,p.',n))).*(n>=0)
```

Comment: I found the problem. Your solution works for matlab 2016b or greater. 
For older version bsxfun function is to be used.

Comment: You right, I wrote it in the answer. I added now the `bsxfun` solution as well.